# Is it possible to download the manual from the Wiki and integrate it into the help menu?

Tags: documentation

Is it possible to download a PDF/HTML snapshot of the Blender Manual from the Wiki and integrate into Blender's help menu?

Comment: Please, don't just downvote and vote to close, give a reason, or suggest an improvement.

Comment: so, you want to access a local version of your manual, instead of the online version? Is that correct?

Comment: @satishgoda yep :)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**You cannot directly download the blender wiki**… well not as normally as you are asking, there are ways (and even if you did get it, as far as *implementing or getting its content into Blender, that's another story*).

You can reach the manual from *inside* Blender however and *some documentation functionality is already implemented somewhat..*

Hover over a button and you should see a short description etc.. This can be useful for getting operator names.

[image]

For more information, right click on the component in Blender and **you can choose to go to the [Online Manual](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Render)** or the [Online Python Reference](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_67_release/bpy.ops.render.html#bpy.ops.render.render)

[image]

You can also just grab a [zip](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_67_release/contents.html) of the python reference for offline viewing directly from the front page.

Comment: +1 It would be nice if Blender has an user preference that enables us to download the docs and tell Blender to use it instead.

Answer (score 4):

There are many download managers (such as wget) that can crawl the wiki and make a local copy (could also be scripted via python). But make sure your use case is covered by [fair use](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fair_use).

For integration you'll need to override the [bpy.ops.wm.doc_view](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_67_1/bpy.ops.wm.html?highlight=wm.doc_view#bpy.ops.wm.doc_view) and [bpy.ops.wm.doc_view_manual](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_67_1/bpy.ops.wm.html?highlight=wm.doc_view#bpy.ops.wm.doc_view_manual) classes to load from a local [configured path](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/1732/290).

Comment: I purposely left out web crawlers as there might be some legal issues involved some places..

Answer (score 2):

partial answer (pdf snapshot):

I have done wiki manual > pdf several times in the past.

last update is form july 1st 2013, so quite up to date I hope...

I dont'know how to link this pdf from blender itself but it would be great...

last conversion is here
https://archive.org/details/BlenderWikiManualPdf20130701

if you care, details, updates and future versions (links) will be posted around here, atm:
http://amrc.altervista.org/nuova-versione-del-blender-wiki-manual-pdf/

--dec 2015 edit--

I even forgot I wrote this answer in 2013... : latest version of that PDF was november 2014, https://archive.org/details/BlenderWikiPDFManual
then the wiki freezed...

Now, a year later, there is an official downloadable html manual from the manual page at http://www.blender.org/manual, the direct link atm is http://www.blender.org/manual/blender_manual.zip. A PDF version is (weirdly) still to be generated from that manual system, but I'll try soon to again generate periodically a PDF from this official html for anyone to share, somewhere.

hth

Marco