# Align view to selected operator (numpad .) when scripting?

Tags: scripting, operator

Whenever I hit <kbd>Numpad</kbd><kbd>.</kbd> *(align view to selection)*, it doesn't show up in the info panel. Is there an operator for this, so that I can use it in scripting?

Comment: This could be phrased as a more general question since it applies to any menu item you want to know the python command to.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The operator name is `bpy.ops.view3d.view_selected()`. See my [answer here for additional information on this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/84/download-the-manual-from-the-wiki-and-integrate-it-into-the-help-menu/85#85) and also how to quickly reach the online manual and the API reference. Here are the accompanying [docs](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_67_1/bpy.ops.view3d.html#bpy.ops.view3d.view_selected) for the operator.

> Hover over a button and you should see a short description etc.. This
>   can be useful for getting operator names.

You can go to the 3d view header and go to *View > Align View > View Selected* and check the operator name there.

[image]

### Copy To Clipboard

While your mouse is over the menu item you can press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> and the Python command gets copied to the clipboard to save you retyping it.

### Log Everything

Some operators are excluded from the report window because typically you don't want setting the cursor (for example) to be logged, however this can be overridden by either...

- Starting blender with the command line argument `--debug-wm`
- Running this in the python console `bpy.app.debug_wm = True`

Then output of all operators executed will be logged in the info space and the console.

Comment: I knew about the hover trick, but I couldn't find the "View Selected" operator in the view menu.

Comment: You can also search in the Input tab of the user preferences if it has a hotkey