# Storing preferences without having properties in every scene?

Tags: scripting, properties

I did applink for 3dCoat app. I set Export directory manually. At present, i should set the directory in every blend scene. But i would like to set the directory path only one time and store it aways in cache. Is it possible to do?

My code:

```
            exchangedir = StringProperty(
            name="FilePath",
            subtype="DIR_PATH"
        )
.....

row.prop(simple3Dcoat, "exchangedir", text="ExchangeDir")
```

It would be cool to store "exchangedir" string in cache. So that it will be always the same for all blend files. Thank you!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This sounds like you would want to have a user-preference for the addon,
Blender supports this through [`bpy.types.AddonPreferences`](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_67_release/bpy.types.AddonPreferences.html)

This way, the addon can have settings that are saved with the user defaults.

API docs include example usage.

Comment: If someone wants to check it. I added this code here https://code.google.com/p/blender-addons-by-mifth/source/browse/#hg%2Fio_simple_3dcoat